# Laravel get employee have been hired for n months

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

Let's say in my employee table I have a column 'hire_date', I want the employee who has the tenure of 1-3 months or simply only 3-month old employees by 'hire_date'.

I tried this:

```
Employee::whereDate('hire_date', '<=', Carbon::now()->subMonths(3))
          ->orderBy('hire_date', 'desc')
          ->get();
```

But it returns all the employees.

I printed the raw query and it is just going back 3 months from the current date and then fetching the records.

```
date(`hire_date`) <= 2020-02-22 //whereDate('hire_date', '<=', Carbon::now()->subMonths(3)
```

What am I doing wrong?
Any Idea to achieve this?

Example:
Jhon an employee was hired in a company on 01/Feb/2020.
So when he completes his 3 months in the company I want to do something by fetching his records.

Answer (score 0):

So for all person hired between the first and the last dayof the month

```
Employee::whereDate('hire_date', '>=', Carbon::now()->subMonths(3)->firstOfMonth())
          ->whereDate('hire_date', '<=', Carbon::now()->subMonths(3)->lastOfMonth())  
          ->orderBy('hire_date', 'desc')
          ->get();
```

so that

```
date(`hire_date`) <= '2020-02-1' AND date(`hire_date`) >= '2020-02-29'
```

Comment: i am confused, what exactly do you want, could you show in an example please

Comment: Update question with example.

Comment: are they all hired at the first of the month?

Comment: the date does not matter in my case month does, but you can take it into account.

Comment: try the new query then

Comment: Thanks, I am trying it let's see.

Answer (score 0):

Problem:
Jhon an employee was hired in a company on 01/Feb/2020. So when he completes his 3 months in the company I want to do something by fetching his records.

Solution for your issue is,

```
$datetime = new DateTime('NOW'); //Current date
$datetime->modify('- 3 months'); //Date before 3 months
$backDate = datetime->format('Y-m-d'); //Format date

$employees = Employee::whereDate('hire_date', $backDate)
                          ->orderBy('hire_date', 'desc')
                          ->get();
```

Comment: This will only work once if the ```current date - 3 months``` falls on the hire date, it won't work if it is more then 3 months and I want to get the employee's records again.